# Java -- how to loop a quiz until the user decides to quit?

Tags: java, while-loop, prompt

I have the following simple Java program that prompts a user with a subtraction quiz. Can someone nudge me along in the right path of how I can implement a loop that keeps generating numbers, doing the calculations, prompting the user, and giving feedback until the user chooses to stop? I imagine it would involve a while loop, but how would the user signal that they want to stop? I understand I could tell them to "press ___ whenever you want to quit", but the rest of the program is constantly prompting for the user to enter an integer...so what if they choose to enter a key to quit (suppose "Q") when the next question is given to them and the computer is waiting for a command-line response that is an integer (since Q is not an integer)?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathQuiz
{

    public static void main( String [] args )
    {

        // random number generator
        Random rng = new Random();


        // scanner to get user's answer
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );


        // generates random number, 1 <= n <= 9
        int num1 = rng.nextInt( 10 );
        int num2 = rng.nextInt( 10 );


        // prompt, answer, user's answer, and feedback
        String prompt = "What is " + num1 + " - " + num2 + "?";
        int answer = Math.abs( num1 - num2 );
        int userAnswer = 0;
        String feedback = "That's correct, way to go!";


        // figure out which is larger
        if( num1 < num2 )
        {
            prompt= "What is " + num2 + " - " + num1 + "?";
        }

        System.out.println( prompt );
        userAnswer = scan.nextInt();


        if( userAnswer != answer )
        {
            feedback = "That is incorrect.";
        }

        System.out.println( feedback );


    }


}
```

Comment: You can do that by wrapping the contents of your `main` method into a loop. [More about while loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) , [And for loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: In addition to what Titus said, you can check if the user inputted an exit string (CTRL C, "exit" etc.) and return if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove the latest `if`

```
if( userAnswer != answer )
{
    feedback = "That is incorrect.";
}
```

and edit it to

```
do
{
    String feedback ;
    /*
    your program here
    */
    System.out.println("again 'Y'") ;
    choice= scan.nextLine() ;
}while("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(choice))
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with everything in java, but from what I just read on Oracle's site, it seems the do-while loop is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you! Just to clarify, the String feedback is for my feedback for the user. If you could fix that, I will go ahead and accept your answer!