# How do I continue to loop until the user wants to quit?

Tags: java, methods

Java
How do I continue to loop until the user wants to quit? I have tried inserting a do while loop but no matter where I put it, it doesn't seem to work. it keeps giving me an error message. I want to loop this until the user doesn't want to enter a score anymore. so it will continue to prompt for another letter grade until they type a "Y" or "N". Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gradeConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int score = 0;
            int minimum = 0;
            int maximum = 100;
            int grade = 0;
            

            System.out.println("Enter letter grade 0-100: ");
            score = scan.nextInt();
            if (!isValidNumber(score,1,100))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        getLetterGrade(score);
        }
        private static boolean isValidNumber(int number, int minimum, int maximum)
        {
            return number > minimum && number<=maximum;
        }
        private static String getLetterGrade(int score)
        {
            String grade=null;
            if(score >=80 && score <90) {
                System.out.println("B");//java code tells you that your letter grade is a B if you input a score that is between and includes 90 and 80
                grade = "B";
            }
            else  if(score <= 100 && score >= 90) {
                System.out.println("A");//java code tells you that your letter grade is a A if you input a score that is between and includes 100 and 90
                grade = "A";
            }else if(60>score){
                System.out.println("F");
                grade = "F";
            }
            return grade;
            
        }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java -- how to loop a quiz until the user decides to quit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320315/java-how-to-loop-a-quiz-until-the-user-decides-to-quit)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use while loop until the user wants to quit. Add a condition on user prompt input and if the user tries to quit, just break the loop.

Also, you're exiting the system if the user gives invalid input. What you can do is, you can continue the program to make the user give a valid input.

```
while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter letter grade 0-100: ");
        score = scan.nextInt();
        if (!isValidNumber(score, minimum, maximum)) {
            System.out.println("The input is not in valid range!");
            continue;
        }
        letterGrade = getLetterGrade(score);
        System.out.println("The corresponding letter grade is: " + letterGrade);
        if (!doContinue(scan)) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

The do continue function just checks whether the user wants to continue or not. Returns a boolean:

```
private static boolean doContinue(Scanner sc) {
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n): ");
    String input = sc.next();
    return input.toLowerCase().equals("y");
}
```

Also, instead of printing the grades while checking condition, you can just return it, just as I've done in the above segment:

```
private static String getLetterGrade(int score) {
    if (score >= 80 && score < 90) {
        return  "B";
    } else if (score >= 90 && score <= 100) {
        return  "A";
    } else if (score < 60) {
        return "F";
    } else {
        return "Unknown Grade";
    }
}
```

And I guess you can change the min max range too, for a proper practical input:

```
private static boolean isValidNumber(int number, int minimum, int maximum) {
    return number >= minimum && number <= maximum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code a bit, and added the possibility to say a grade or N in the same field.

I also added the possibility to loop until an incorrect value or a N value is typed, using a simple while condition

Just have a look and feel free to modify it again

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gradeConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int minimum = 1;
        int maximum = 100;
        String grade;
        boolean keep_going = true;

        while(keep_going) {
            System.out.println("Enter letter grade 0-100: ");
            grade = scan.nextLine();
            if (!isValidChoice(grade, minimum, maximum)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice!");
                keep_going = false;
                break;
            }
            if(grade.toLowerCase().equals("n"))
                keep_going = false;
            else
                getLetterGrade(Integer.parseInt(grade));
        }
    }
    private static boolean isValidChoice(String value, int minimum, int maximum)
    {
        if(value.toLowerCase().equals("n"))
            return true;
        try {
            int letter = Integer.parseInt(value);
            return letter > minimum && letter<=maximum;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private static String getLetterGrade(int score)
    {
        String grade=null;
        if(score >=80 && score <90) {
            System.out.println("B");//java code tells you that your letter grade is a B if you input a score that is between and includes 90 and 80
            grade = "B";
        }
        else  if(score <= 100 && score >= 90) {
            System.out.println("A");//java code tells you that your letter grade is a A if you input a score that is between and includes 100 and 90
            grade = "A";
        }else if(60>score){
            System.out.println("F");
            grade = "F";
        }
        return grade;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gradeConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        char opt;
        int score = 0;
        int minimum = 0;
        int maximum = 100;
        int grade = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter letter grade 0-100: ");
            score = scan.nextInt();
            if (!isValidNumber(score, 1, 100)) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            getLetterGrade(score);
            System.out.println("Do yu wish to continue?: ");
            opt = Character.toLowerCase(scan.next().charAt(0));
        } while (opt == 'y');
    }

    private static boolean isValidNumber(int number, int minimum, int maximum) {
        return number > minimum && number <= maximum;
    }

    private static String getLetterGrade(int score) {
        String grade = null;
        if (score >= 80 && score < 90) {
            System.out.println("B");// java code tells you that your letter grade is a B if you input a score that
                                    // is between and includes 90 and 80
            grade = "B";
        } else if (score <= 100 && score >= 90) {
            System.out.println("A");// java code tells you that your letter grade is a A if you input a score that
                                    // is between and includes 100 and 90
            grade = "A";
        } else if (60 > score) {
            System.out.println("F");
            grade = "F";
        }
        return grade;

    }
}
```

The `do ... while` loop works for this but you might want to refactor your variable declarations to change with newer scores being inputted.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan in a loop and check the entered data for the need to exit it.
I also changed the type of the input value to support this check.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        int minimum = 0;
        int maximum = 100;
        int grade = 0;


        System.out.println("Enter letter grade 0-100: ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        while (!input.equals("y") || !input.equals("n")) {
            int score = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (!isValidNumber(score,1,100)) {
                getLetterGrade(score);
            }
            input = scan.nextLine();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```